# For AWS AutoScaling - how many servers have to agree?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm unable to find docs around this so please point them out where it mentions this....

Assume I have an autoscale group with 3 servers and I want to add more servers when CPU crossed X percent. How many of those servers have to be over x percent before the scaling policy takes action?

Comment: You might be able to define that parameter with a load balancer policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: there isn't a fixed number.

A scaling policy is an action taken into when a cloudwatch alarm is triggered.

It's up to you to define what that alarm is. The easiest metric is probably the cpu utilisation aggregated by autoscaling group. As well as picking the metric you need to pick how it is aggregated (Amazon calls this the statistic)

If you pick the 'average' statistic then it averages the cpu utilisation across your instances, so there's no fixed number of instances that triggers the policy. Assuming your threshold was 50%, if two servers were at 45% and one was at 60 then the alarm should trigger, but if 1 server was at 45% and 2 servers were at 51% then it wouldn't trigger.

You could also set your alarm to be trigger by the maximum: as soon as there a 5 minute period where there is always a server > 50% (it needn't always be the same one), or by the minimum: when all of the servers are above the threshold